# Powershell ADgroupMembers convertto-HTML messed up

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a multi purpose report to query Share permissions and group members who have access.

All the data is shown in a table on screen, or outputted to a file, but I'm having trouble with **Convertto-HTML/CSV**. Apparently due to not using original properties. Everything I try fails... Anyone able to figure out what can be the issue or have a solution?  [You can see the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbTFQ.png).

```
Function Get-Membr {

$Groups = Get-Acl $UNC | 
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | 
      Where-Object { (-not $_.IsInherited) -and ('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM','BUILTIN\Administrators','CREATOR OWNER','BUILTIN\Users' -notcontains $_.IdentityReference) } | 
      Select-Object -Exp IdentityReference  

foreach ($Group in $Groups)
        { $group | ft Value,Name,Department #| ConvertTo-HTML 
          $group.Translate('System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier').Value |
          Get-ADGroupMember -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
          Get-ADObject -Properties name, Department | 
          select name, Department |
          ft -HideTableHeaders Value,Name,Department #| ConvertTo-HTML #| out-file -append $tmp
        }
}
```

EDIT / UPDATE:
I was able to solve the issue myself by:

```
Function Get-Membr {

$Groups = Get-Acl $UNC | 
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | 
      Where-Object { (-not $_.IsInherited) -and ('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM','BUILTIN\Administrators','CREATOR OWNER','BUILTIN\Users' -notcontains $_.IdentityReference) } | 
      Select-Object -Exp IdentityReference

$global:Results2 = foreach ($Group in $Groups){
$group.Translate('System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier').Value |
Get-ADGroupMember -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property     @{l="GroupName";e={$Group}}, Name, @{name="Description";expression={(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties Description).Description}},@{name="Enabled";expression={((Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName).Enabled)}},@{name="- - Action - -";e={(get-aduser -identity $_.Manager -properties DisplayName).DisplayName}}
}
}
```

[You can see the End result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huUCz.png)

Comment: Just FYI - your obfuscation of names and whatnot in the screenshot is not very effective.

Comment: You can't do `ConvertTo-HTML` after `Format-Table` (which you have aliased as `ft`). Remove the `| ft ..` parts and change these to `ConvertTo-HTML`.

Comment: @Gvee.. uploaded a better picture. 
(i'll try your comment Mark, think i already tried it)